# sql: long to wide format without using PIVOT

Tags: sql, database, group-by, pivot

I have a table like the following:

```
user_id time_id val0 val1 val2 actual_value score
1       1       1    0     0   0           0.6
1       1       0    1     0   1           0.4
1       1       0    0     1   2           0.3
1       2       1    0     0   0           0.7
1       2       0    1     0   1           0.4
1       2       0    0     1   2           0.3
2       1       1    0     0   0           0.9
2       1       0    1     0   1           0.5
2       1       0    0     1   2           0.4
```

I want to convert the data to wide format like the following:

```
user_id time_id  score_0 score_1 score_2
1       1           0.6.    0.3.    0.3
1       2           0.7.    0.4.    0.3
2       1           0.9.    0.5.    0.4
```

the SQL I used does not have a pivot choice so I am wondering how to convert the long format to wide without using PIVOT.

Comment: why does valid comments are deleted? it's still not clear how the first line got achieved. that was pointed out by another user but got deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    user_id,
    time_id,
    max(case when val0 = 1 then score end) score0,
    max(case when val1 = 1 then score end) score1,
    max(case when val2 = 1 then score end) score2
from mytable
group by user_id, time_id
```

Maybe you want to use `actual_value` to pivot instead of the `val[n]` columns:

```
select
    user_id,
    time_id,
    max(case when actual_value = 0 then score end) score0,
    max(case when actual_value = 1 then score end) score1,
    max(case when actual_value = 2 then score end) score2
from mytable
group by user_id, time_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select user_id, time_id,
       max(case when actual_value = 0 then score end) as score_0,
       max(case when actual_value = 1 then score end) as score_1,
       max(case when actual_value = 2 then score end) as score_2
from t
group by user_id, time_id;
```